# I do not understand the logic behind this code

Tags: c

I already coded a similar function, it is call get_next_line and at each call it returns a string to the current line. But I found someone who did it surprisingly easily and could not understand his code totally. I would love some help from you guys.

```
char *get_next_line(const int fd)
{
  static int    last = 1;
  static int    rd = 0;
  static int    i = 0;
  static char   *res = NULL;
  static char   buff[READ_MAX];

  if (buff[my_length(buff) - rd] == '\0')
    {
      if ((rd = read(fd, buff, READ_MAX)) <= 0)
        return (res = (last-- && buff[my_length(buff) - rd - 1] != 10) ? res : NULL);
      buff[rd] = '\0';
    }
  if ((res = (i == 0) ? malloc(sizeof(*res) * READ_MAX + 1) :
       my_realloc(res, sizeof(*res) * READ_MAX + 1)) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  while (buff[my_length(buff) - rd] && buff[my_length(buff) - rd] != '\n')
    res[i++] = buff[my_length(buff) - rd--];
  res[i] = '\0';
  if (buff[my_length(buff) - rd] == '\n')
    {
      i = 0;
      rd--;
      return (res);
    }
  return (get_next_line(fd));
}
```

For example, I don't understand :

```
return (res = (last-- && buff[my_length(buff) - rd - 1] != 10) ? res : NULL);
```

What does the '?' and ':' mean? Does it mean for the condition before '?' return res or NULL?

It is a rather large question, but thanks for your help anyways.

PS : READ_MAX's value is 5 in a header file.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  I don't understand it either, it's a plie of gunge.

Comment: I wouldn't say "surprisingly easily", it's very hard to read, totally uncommented, and the code structure is nearly completely hidden. Try to start from this code, then simplify it a little at a time, doing only one operation per line of code. Hopefully the structure will pop out.

Comment: the `my_length()` function is called too often, IMHO. What does it do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
What does the '?' and ':' mean?
```

This is called [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) in `C`. An example is here,

```
result = a > b ? x : y;
```

is equivalent to,

```
if (a > b) {
  result = x;
} else {
  result = y;
}
```

Now about making you understand the code posted, most if it are standard function calls such as `read()`, `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `sizeof()`, string termination with `\0`  etc., I suggest going through each line one by one would really help you in learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (res = (last-- && buff[my_length(buff) - rd - 1] != 10) ? res : NULL);
```

Here `?:` is a ternary operator . If the expression before the `?` turns out to be TRUE then the value immediately after `?` gets executed else the latter one after `:` gets executed.

This is same as

```
if((last--) && (buff[my_length(buff) - rd - 1] != 10))
{
   res = res;
}
else
{
   res = NULL;
}
return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ternary operator.Refer this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

```
( if the condition is true)?it will execute:or else it will execute;
```

In this case

```
(res = (last-- && buff[my_length(buff) - rd - 1] != 10) ? res : NULL);
```

if the condition `(res = (last-- && buff[my_length(buff) - rd - 1] != 10)` is true then `res` will return. If the condition is false, then `NULL` will return.

It is equal to this.

```
if ( (res = (last-- && buff[my_length(buff) - rd - 1] ) != 10 )
{
     return (res=res);
}
else 
{
     return (res=NULL);
}
```